# Pass data between components react-rails

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

There are three components and I want to pass the data from `calendar` to `ItemForm` component through `Main`.

`Main` Component:

```
var Main = createReactClass({

 getInitialState() {
   return { items: [] ,
        }
 },     

 componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log(this.state.start) // Start is here
 },

 getStartEnd(start, end) {
   this.setState({start: start});
   this.setState({end: end});
   },

 render() {

return (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/calendar" render={() => <Calendar items={this.state.items} getStartEnd={this.getStartEnd}/>}></Route>
    <Route path="/itemform" render={(props) => <ItemForm {...props} start={this.state.start} end={this.state.end} />}></Route>
    <Route path="/itemshow/:id" render={(props) => <ItemShow {...props} />}></Route>
  </Router>
);
}
});
```

`calendar` component:
getStartEnd(start, end) is called inside this component.

`ItemForm` component :

```
var ItemForm = createReactClass({

  componentDidMount () {
  },

  componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log(this.props.start) // Is undefined 
  },

  render() {
   var start = this.props.start // Is undefined 
  return (
    <div>
     {start}
    </div>
   );
 }
});
```

It looks like `start` and `end` is passed from `calendar` to `main` component but can not be passed to `ItemForm`? What am I missing?

Comment: when you call `getStartEnd(start, end)` in `Calendar` component is it updating the state in `Main` component ? The reason you're getting `undefined` in `ItemForm` is you didn't initialised them in the `Main` component state

Comment: It updates the `state` in `Main`. If I initialize them , then it does not get the update `state` it gets empty string which is the value when I  initialized them.

Comment: may i know how you are navigating ?

Comment: I did not add that yet, but it should not be difficult , just a redirect function by `history.push` can do it.

Comment: i implemented a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacr-router-component-rendering-lg1w6) and that is working for me. You can check it in console.

Comment: I have exactly the same code in another project without using `react-router-dom` , it works there as well, but here when I am using `Route` and `Router` it does not work.

Comment: when you use `Route and Router` it depends on how you're navigating. If you just change the url and reload the whole state is cleared. As you are using different routes to render the components it's better to use `react-router-dom`